# How to find an EC2 instance by public IP?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I'm trying to write a command line tool to manage my EC2 instances.

In the environment I will be running the tool, only the public IPs of the instances are available, so I need a way to get EC2 instance IDs by IP so that I can call methods like `reboot`.

I've checked the documentation. There's a method called `filter` that looks promising, but I can't find the documentation that shows how to use it to filter by public IPs.

How can I do this?

Comment: It's possible. Are you planning on using CLI or any Language specific SDK to get the required info in your tool?. Based on that I can give you some example.

Comment: @Imran I'm going to use the Python AWS SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example with boto3 SDK.

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('ec2')
response = client.describe_instances(
    Filters=[
        {
            'Name': 'ip-address',
            'Values': [
                '54.x.x.x',
            ]
        },
    ]
)
response ['Reservations'][0]['Instances'][0]['InstanceId']
//'i-0aaxxxxxxxxxxx'
```

Reference - 
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_instances